# Add only to negative days in dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, time, difference

I have a dataframe where I obtained a difference column between two different hours (below an example):

```
    difference 
    00:30:15 
    00:15:00
    -1 days +02:27:00
    -1 days +00:41:00
```

those values are marked as timedelta type. So how can I add one day only for those negative values (to turn positive the difference)? I have tried to do:

```
mask=df[df["difference"]<"0"]
df[mask,"difference"]=df["difference"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

(quote marks for zero because otherwise dont accept it, dont know why)

output:

> TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

and then I try:

```
df.loc[df["difference"]<0, "difference"]=df["difference"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

output:

> TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

So, I dont know what else can be done. I have reviewed a lot of questions here but none has helped me so far. Any ideas are welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. `mask` should be a boolean array, not a dataframe:

```
mask=df["difference"]<"0" # << Note the change
df.loc[mask,"difference"]=df["difference"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  difference
0   00:30:15
1   00:15:00
2   02:27:00
3   00:41:00
```

Comment: Yes it did. I still struggle with different kinds of values after operations. Whenever warnings come out sometimes I cant see the error because of that. Thank you very much, it was solved right away!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['difference'] < '0', 'difference'] = df["difference"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: This is similar to the below one. Very clever both, they worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use dtype to figure out what the type of the values in the column are? If they are not date types, you will have problems comparing.

Comment: The question has been solved, thank you but I did it, they were datetime64. So there were no problems for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt almost makes it... but, as explained in the exception, you cannot compare `pd.Timedelta < int`, with `0` being the integer in this case.

You can fix it with

```
df.loc[df["difference"] < pd.Timedelta(0), "difference"]=df["difference"] + pd.Timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: HTH, notice Chris and Andy's answers work as well, often there are multiple ways to do a job, some work better in certain cases, but it is good to know the options